# Lightbox and smoothscroll jumps

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have a couple of issues with this website: http://niclamarino.altervista.org/Layouts/Beeline/5.html

- Whenever you click on the Menu links, the screen "jumps", showing a 0.2 seconds screen and then working properly.
- In the Lightbox section (Characters section), the lightbox opens after scrolling down to the bottom of the page.

How can I solve these problems? I am not a jquery programmer at all! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your question**
this line `$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {` that makes the site scroll. it basically says to take effect in all a tag with a # in the beginning of their href.

So if you want to limit this effect add #menu `$('#menu a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {` wich is the id for thw div wrapping your menu so it only affects link inside that div

Your script for smooth scroll on the menu still has a glitch, you should look for another in google

**Other things i noticed and may cause other issues**
You are loading 2 different version of jQuery. Delete one. If you keep jQuery 2x here is an snippet for smoothscroll

```
$('#menu a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').on('click',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = this.hash;
  $target = $(target);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop':  $target.offset().top
  }, 800, 'swing');
});
```

Place your scripts at the end, before closing the body or before closing head

You don't have closing tag for head, body nor html

Css should be external

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried adding the #menu id, the smoothscrolling works but I still get the glitch, I've looked for other smoothscrolling snippets but they all look alike and present the same "jumping" problem (Or generate a conflict with the lightbox).
The snipped you wrote doesn't work unfortunately :c

Is there any other way I can solve it?

Thank your for making me notice about the double jquery. As for the css, etc, it's still in a development mode so I am keeping the css inside the page itself in order to make the coding faster.

Comment: When I tested it I didn't get the glitch. Something it's messing with it. What I do in this kind of situation is to start adding chunks of code in a blank html until I start getting the bug, then adding shorter chunks to narrow what's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for you reply! I've finally fixed it adding "return false" to the script,  now it shows no glitch and the lightbox works perfectly. Thank you for your help!